# How do i get time in long format from this string "Monday, 27 April 2015 12:12:10 am India Standard Time"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

Am getting this string "Monday, 27 April 2015 12:12:10 am India Standard Time" when i select any time in my UIDatePicker (only time mode).

When i do

```
 `NSLog(@"%@",[self.timePicker.date descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]);`
```

I can see my selected time along with date and other time zone details in console.

```
 Monday, 27 April 2015 12:12:10 am India Standard Time
```

How do i extract only time part and  convert  time part (12:12:10 am) to long format ??

Code for converting NSDate to long format

```
 long timeInLong=[date timeIntervalSince1970]*1000;
```

But please tell me how to get time part from that console string.

I have tried this and Liam getting "null" as output

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
    // if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm aa"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    // voila!
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[self.timePicker.date descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];

    NSLog(@"%@",dateFromString); //null
```

Please help

UPDATES :

now am getting output like this with following code

```
output    2015-04-27 13:17:56 +0000
```

CODE:

```
   NSDate* sourceDate = self.timePicker.date;

    NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
    NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
    NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

    NSDate* destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate];


    NSString *dateOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", destinationDate];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateOutput);
```

Still am now able to separate that time part  .

Comment: do you want time from your input date? or what is your input? what is your required output?

Comment: yes, i want 12:12 am in NSDate (without date part)

Comment: `NSDate` objects represent a point in time, which always consists of both date and time. There's no such thing as a "`NSDate` without date part". Now, when you represent this `NSDate` as a string with only the time, you can create a formatter that only outputs the time string. -- Perhaps you should step back and explain the broader problem you're trying to solve and we might be able to offer better counsel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
    NSDate* sourceDate = self.timePicker.date;

    NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:sourceDate
                                                          dateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle
                                                          timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

output format is 4:00:00 pm